# Datatables vertical scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I've already [posted](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/25845/scrolly-with-height-bigger-than-actual-table-height-with-scrollcollapse-causes-unwanted-scrollbars) this on the datatables forum but no response after a few days. So I hope someone here can at least come up with a workaround for this.

I've been hammering on this problem for the past few days but can't find any solution... I have a website were dataTables is used on a search results page, so it must be able to handle a few records, or many.
I wanted to use vertical scrolling to make sure the headers stay visible no matter how many records are found, but this is giving me a headache...

See the following jsfiddle which demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kzgq1L25/2/

I initialize datatables like so:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true
    , "scrollY" : "500px"
    , "scrollCollapse": true
    , "paging": false
    , "searching": false
    , "ordering": true
});
```

Which tells it to create a vertical scroll container with a height of 500px. The `"scollCollapse": true` tells it to not make the vertical scroll container 500px, if the table itself is less high than that (to avoid empty white space).

My problem, is as you can see, there is always a vertical scrollbar being added, even when the table height is less than the given height in the `scrollYparameter`. This is only happens when also using `"scrollCollapse": true`. In the example the table consists just of 2 rows, and according to Chrome developer tools, the tbody element is just 62px big, and I've given the `"scrollY": "500px"` parameter to dataTables, so I would expect to NOT have a vertical scrollbar.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
    .dataTables_scrollBody{ height:500px !important;}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really solve the issue, it just makes the table fixed 500px high, which would be the same as removing `"scrollCollapse": true` from the datatable intiialisation. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score -1):

When you remove the margin from the table element, your vertical scrollbar issue is fixed, also in your jsfiddle:

```
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11941837)

Comment: I edited it so now I think it does answers the question.